# Increasing loss funcion in elementary example

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, regression

I want to predict ideal linear data (identical function)

```
data = np.asarray(range(100),dtype=np.float32)
```

I use to this linear function

```
model = Sequential([
    Dense(1, input_shape=(1,))
])

model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse')

model.fit(data, data, epochs=10, batch_size=100)
```

but my loss function is increasing. What is wrong with this simple code?

```
Epoch 1/10
100/100 [==============================] - 1s 7ms/step - loss: 3559.4075
Epoch 2/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 20us/step - loss: 14893056.0000
Epoch 3/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 170us/step - loss: 62314639360.0000
Epoch 4/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 30us/step - loss: 260733187129344.0000
Epoch 5/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 70us/step - loss: 1090944439330799616.0000
Epoch 6/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 20us/step - loss: 4564665060617919397888.0000
Epoch 7/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 30us/step - loss: 19099198494067630815576064.0000
Epoch 8/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 30us/step - loss: 79913699011849558249925771264.0000
Epoch 9/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 50us/step - loss: 334370041805433555342669660553216.0000
Epoch 10/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 20us/step - loss: 1399051141583436919510296595359858688.0000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to standardize input features. And you can learn [How and why do normalization and feature scaling work?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41704/how-and-why-do-normalization-and-feature-scaling-work). Let me just use `(x-mean(x))/std(x)`as an example here.

```
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential

data = np.asarray(range(100),dtype=np.float32)
model = Sequential([
    Dense(1, input_shape=(1,))
])

model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse')
model.fit((data-np.mean(data))/np.std(data), data, epochs=200, batch_size=100) 

Epoch 1/200
100/100 [==============================] - 3s 26ms/step - loss: 3284.6235
Epoch 2/200
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 25us/step - loss: 3154.5522
Epoch 3/200
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 22us/step - loss: 3029.6318
...
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 27us/step - loss: 1.1016
Epoch 200/200
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 28us/step - loss: 1.0579
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but I still do not understand why without regulization it wont work. Every step this algorithm  try to find maximal gradient (direction of maximal decrease of loss function) ..... But after update loss is bigger. (I dont use additional methods like momentum.)

Comment: @Newbie In fact, you can also try to use a small enough learning rate like `lr=0.0001` in SDG besides regularization to get the above results. The essential problem is that the model can't converge and the parameters are updated blindly like your question. Excessive learning rate leads to the model can't find the global minimum. Regularization can make the loss function more smooth and accelerate the convergence of the model. In addition, if you use optimization methods similar to `Adam`  to iterate many times, you can also get the above results.